# "error: (1098) conflicting declarations" when function types changes

Tags: c, embedded, mplab

I get conflicting declarations error when types of function is changed from int to void. The below code gives me error "TimerSetup.c:4: error: (1098) conflicting declarations for variable "_Timer1Init"". But the error vanish if function type of Timer1Init is changed to int in TimerSetup.h and TimerSetup.c file. Any Idea! Why?

**TimerSetup.h**

```
// TimerSetup.h

    #ifndef XC_HEADER_TEMPLATE_H
        #define XC_HEADER_TEMPLATE_H

        #include <xc.h> // include processor files - each processor file is guarded.  
        #include <stdint.h>

        void Timer1Init();           //<-----Error vanish when type changed to int


        #ifdef  __cplusplus
        extern "C" {
        #endif /* __cplusplus */

            // TODO If C++ is being used, regular C code needs function names to have C 
            // linkage so the functions can be used by the c code. 

        #ifdef  __cplusplus
        }
        #endif /* __cplusplus */

        #endif  /* XC_HEADER_TEMPLATE_H */
```

**TimerSetup.c**

```
#include <xc.h>
#include "TimerSetup.h"

void Timer1Init()             //<-----Error vanish when type changed to int
{ 
    PIE1bits.TMR1IE=1;        
    PIR1bits.TMR1IF=0;   
}
```

**Wifi.c**

```
   #include <xc.h>
    #include "Wifi.h"
    void eUart1Init()
    {   
        TRISB=0;
        TRISC6=0;        /* Make Tx pin as output*/
        TRISC7=1;        /* Make Rx pin as input*/
        TXSTA1 = 0;
        TXSTA1bits.BRGH    = 1;                // high baud rate
        BAUDCON1bits.BRG16 = 0;
        BAUDCON1 = 0;
        PMD0 = 0;

        TXSTA1bits.TX9 = 0;
        TXSTA1bits.TXEN = 1;  
        TXSTA1bits.SENDB = 0;
        TXSTA1bits.BRGH = 1;

        RCSTA1bits.SPEN = 1;
        RCSTA1bits.RX9 = 0;
        RCSTA1bits.CREN = 1;
        RCSTA2bits.CREN = 1;
        SPBRG1 = 51;

        IPR1bits.TX1IP = 0;    // Interrupt priority bit
        PIR1bits.TX1IF = 0;
        PIE1bits.TX1IE = 1; 

        IPR1bits.RC1IP = 0;    // Interrupt priority bit /////////
        PIR1bits.RC1IF = 0;
        PIE1bits.RC1IE = 1; 
    }
    void eUart2Init()
    {   
        TRISB6=0;        /* Make Tx2 pin as output*/
        TRISB7=1;        /* Make Rx2 pin as input*/
        TXSTA2 = 0;
        TXSTA2bits.BRGH    = 1;                // high baud rate
        BAUDCON2bits.BRG16 = 0;
        BAUDCON2 = 0;
        //PMD0 = 0;

        TXSTA2bits.TX9 = 0;
        TXSTA2bits.TXEN = 1;  
        TXSTA2bits.SENDB = 0;
        TXSTA2bits.BRGH = 1;

        RCSTA2bits.SPEN = 1;
        RCSTA2bits.RX9 = 0;
        RCSTA2bits.CREN = 1;
        SPBRG2 = 51;

        IPR3bits.TX2IP = 0;    // Interrupt priority bit
        PIR3bits.TX2IF = 0;
        PIE3bits.TX2IE = 1; 

        IPR3bits.RC2IP = 0;    // Interrupt priority bit
        PIR3bits.RC2IF = 0;
        PIE3bits.RC2IE = 1; 
    }
    // EUART1 Put String Function Defines Here
    void eUart1Puts(const char *s)
    {
        while(*s)
            eUart1PutByte(*s++);
    }
    void eUart2Puts(const char *s)
    {
        while(*s)
            eUart2PutByte(*s++);
    }
    void eUart1PutByte(unsigned char byte)
    {
    while((PIR1bits.TX1IF != 1) && (TXSTA1bits.TXEN1 != 0)) // set when register is empty
            continue;
        PIE1bits.TX1IE = 1;
        TXREG1 = byte;
    }
    void eUart2PutByte(unsigned char byte)
    {
    while((PIR3bits.TX2IF != 1) && (TXSTA2bits.TXEN2 != 0)) // set when register is empty
            continue;
        PIE1bits.TX1IE = 1;
        TXREG2 = byte;
    }
    void WifiAT(char *command)
    {
        eUart1Puts(command);
        //__delay_ms(wifi_wait);
        while (eusart_rx_buffer_rd != eusart_rx_buffer_wr) 
            {   // While there's data in the buffer
                eUart2PutByte(eusart_rx_buffer[eusart_rx_buffer_rd++]);   // Do something with it

                if (eusart_rx_buffer_rd >= EUSART_BUFFER_SIZE)     // Increase read pointer
                {
                    eusart_rx_buffer_rd = 0;
                }
            }            
    }
    __interrupt() void ISR(void)             //<----------------------- To here
    {
        if((PIR3bits.TX2IF == 1) && (PIE3bits.TX2IE == 1))  //Debug Terminal Tx  
        {
            PIR3bits.TX2IF = 0;
            PIE3bits.TX2IE = 0;
        }

        if((PIR3bits.RC2IF != 0) && (PIE3bits.RC2IE != 0))  //Debug Terminal Rx
        {         
            PIR3bits.RC2IF = 0;
            rc2_data = RCREG2;      
        }

        if((PIR1bits.TX1IF != 0) && (PIE1bits.TX1IE != 0))        
        {
            PIR1bits.TX1IF = 0;
            PIE1bits.TX1IE = 0;
        }

        if((PIR1bits.RC1IF != 0) && (PIE1bits.RC1IE != 0))
        {         
    //      rc_data = RCREG1;
    //      eUart2PutByte(rc_data);

            eusart_rx_buffer[eusart_rx_buffer_wr++] = RCREG1;  // Store the received data

            if (eusart_rx_buffer_wr >= EUSART_BUFFER_SIZE)    // Increment write pointer
            {
                eusart_rx_buffer_wr = 0;
            }

            PIR1bits.RC1IF = 0;
        }

    //    if((PIR1bits.TMR1IF != 0) && (PIE1bits.TMR1IE != 0))
    //    {
    //        int flag = 0;
    //        TMR1=0xF856;
    //        if(flag >= 1000)
    //        {
    //            PORTCbits.RC1 = ~(PORTCbits.RC1);
    //            PIR1bits.TMR1IF=0;  /* Make Timer1 Overflow Flag to '0' */   
    //        }
    //    }
    }
```

**TokMain.c**

```
    #include <xc.h>
#include "Wifi.h"

void eUart1Init()
{   
    TRISB=0;
    TRISC6=0;        /* Make Tx pin as output*/
    TRISC7=1;        /* Make Rx pin as input*/
    TXSTA1 = 0;
    TXSTA1bits.BRGH    = 1;                // high baud rate
    BAUDCON1bits.BRG16 = 0;
    BAUDCON1 = 0;
    PMD0 = 0;

    TXSTA1bits.TX9 = 0;
    TXSTA1bits.TXEN = 1;  
    TXSTA1bits.SENDB = 0;
    TXSTA1bits.BRGH = 1;

    RCSTA1bits.SPEN = 1;
    RCSTA1bits.RX9 = 0;
    RCSTA1bits.CREN = 1;
    RCSTA2bits.CREN = 1;

    SPBRG1 = 51;

    IPR1bits.TX1IP = 0;    // Interrupt priority bit
    PIR1bits.TX1IF = 0;
    PIE1bits.TX1IE = 1; 

    IPR1bits.RC1IP = 0;    // Interrupt priority bit /////////
    PIR1bits.RC1IF = 0;
    PIE1bits.RC1IE = 1; 
}

void eUart2Init()
{   
    TRISB6=0;        /* Make Tx2 pin as output*/
    TRISB7=1;        /* Make Rx2 pin as input*/
    TXSTA2 = 0;
    TXSTA2bits.BRGH    = 1;                // high baud rate
    BAUDCON2bits.BRG16 = 0;
    BAUDCON2 = 0;
    //PMD0 = 0;

    TXSTA2bits.TX9 = 0;
    TXSTA2bits.TXEN = 1;  
    TXSTA2bits.SENDB = 0;
    TXSTA2bits.BRGH = 1;

    RCSTA2bits.SPEN = 1;
    RCSTA2bits.RX9 = 0;
    RCSTA2bits.CREN = 1;

    SPBRG2 = 51;

    IPR3bits.TX2IP = 0;    // Interrupt priority bit
    PIR3bits.TX2IF = 0;
    PIE3bits.TX2IE = 1; 

    IPR3bits.RC2IP = 0;    // Interrupt priority bit
    PIR3bits.RC2IF = 0;
    PIE3bits.RC2IE = 1; 
}
// EUART1 Put String Function Defines Here
void eUart1Puts(const char *s)
{
    while(*s)
        eUart1PutByte(*s++);
}

void eUart2Puts(const char *s)
{
    while(*s)
        eUart2PutByte(*s++);
}

void eUart1PutByte(unsigned char byte)
{
while((PIR1bits.TX1IF != 1) && (TXSTA1bits.TXEN1 != 0)) // set when register is empty
        continue;
    PIE1bits.TX1IE = 1;
    TXREG1 = byte;
}

void eUart2PutByte(unsigned char byte)
{
while((PIR3bits.TX2IF != 1) && (TXSTA2bits.TXEN2 != 0)) // set when register is empty
        continue;
    PIE1bits.TX1IE = 1;
    TXREG2 = byte;
}

void WifiAT(char *command)
{
    eUart1Puts(command);
    //__delay_ms(wifi_wait);
    while (eusart_rx_buffer_rd != eusart_rx_buffer_wr) 
        {   // While there's data in the buffer
            eUart2PutByte(eusart_rx_buffer[eusart_rx_buffer_rd++]);   // Do something with it

            if (eusart_rx_buffer_rd >= EUSART_BUFFER_SIZE)     // Increase read pointer
            {
                eusart_rx_buffer_rd = 0;
            }
        }            
}

__interrupt() void ISR(void)             //<----------------------- To here
{
    if((PIR3bits.TX2IF == 1) && (PIE3bits.TX2IE == 1))  //Debug Terminal Tx  
    {
        PIR3bits.TX2IF = 0;
        PIE3bits.TX2IE = 0;
    }

    if((PIR3bits.RC2IF != 0) && (PIE3bits.RC2IE != 0))  //Debug Terminal Rx
    {         
        PIR3bits.RC2IF = 0;
        rc2_data = RCREG2;      
    }

    if((PIR1bits.TX1IF != 0) && (PIE1bits.TX1IE != 0))        
    {
        PIR1bits.TX1IF = 0;
        PIE1bits.TX1IE = 0;
    }

    if((PIR1bits.RC1IF != 0) && (PIE1bits.RC1IE != 0))
    {         
//      rc_data = RCREG1;
//      eUart2PutByte(rc_data);

        eusart_rx_buffer[eusart_rx_buffer_wr++] = RCREG1;  // Store the received data

        if (eusart_rx_buffer_wr >= EUSART_BUFFER_SIZE)    // Increment write pointer
        {
            eusart_rx_buffer_wr = 0;
        }

        PIR1bits.RC1IF = 0;
    }

//    if((PIR1bits.TMR1IF != 0) && (PIE1bits.TMR1IE != 0))
//    {
//        int flag = 0;
//        TMR1=0xF856;
//        if(flag >= 1000)
//        {
//            PORTCbits.RC1 = ~(PORTCbits.RC1);
//            PIR1bits.TMR1IF=0;  /* Make Timer1 Overflow Flag to '0' */   
//        }
//    }
}
```

**Wifi.h**

```
// This is a guard condition so that contents of this file are not included
// more than once.  
#ifndef XC_HEADER_TEMPLATE_H
#define XC_HEADER_TEMPLATE_H

#include <xc.h> // include processor files - each processor file is guarded.  
#include <stdint.h>

#define _XTAL_FREQ 8000000UL
#define EUSART_BUFFER_SIZE 1024

char rc2_data; 
char rc_data;

char eusart_rx_buffer[EUSART_BUFFER_SIZE];   // the actual buffer, now 2048 bytes long
uint16_t eusart_rx_buffer_rd = 0;            // the current read position
uint16_t eusart_rx_buffer_wr = 0;            // the current write position

void eUart1Init();
void eUart2Init();
void eUart1PutByte(unsigned char byte);
void eUart2PutByte(unsigned char byte);
void eUart1Puts(const char *s);
void eUart2Puts(const char *s);
void WifiAT(char *command);


// TODO Insert declarations or function prototypes (right here) to leverage 
// live documentation

#ifdef  __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif /* __cplusplus */

    // TODO If C++ is being used, regular C code needs function names to have C 
    // linkage so the functions can be used by the c code. 

#ifdef  __cplusplus
}
#endif /* __cplusplus */

#endif  /* XC_HEADER_TEMPLATE_H */
```

**Full error Message:**

```
make -f nbproject/Makefile-default.mk SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory 'E:/pk/TokenOverWiFi.X'
make  -f nbproject/Makefile-default.mk dist/default/production/TokenOverWiFi.X.production.hex
make[2]: Entering directory 'E:/pk/TokenOverWiFi.X'
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\xc8\v1.44\bin\xc8.exe" --pass1  --chip=18F25K80 -Q -G  --double=24 --float=24 --emi=wordwrite --opt=+asm,+asmfile,-speed,+space,-debug,-local --addrqual=ignore --mode=free -P -N255 --warn=-3 --asmlist -DXPRJ_default=default  --summary=default,-psect,-class,+mem,-hex,-file --output=default,-inhx032 --runtime=default,+clear,+init,-keep,-no_startup,-download,+config,+clib,-plib   --output=-mcof,+elf:multilocs --stack=compiled:auto:auto:auto "--errformat=%f:%l: error: (%n) %s" "--warnformat=%f:%l: warning: (%n) %s" "--msgformat=%f:%l: advisory: (%n) %s"     -obuild/default/production/TokMain.p1 TokMain.c 
TokMain.c:81: warning: (361) function declared implicit int
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\xc8\v1.44\bin\xc8.exe"  --chip=18F25K80 -G -mdist/default/production/TokenOverWiFi.X.production.map  -DXPRJ_default=default  --double=24 --float=24 --emi=wordwrite --opt=+asm,+asmfile,-speed,+space,-debug,-local --addrqual=ignore --mode=free -P -N255 --warn=-3 --asmlist --summary=default,-psect,-class,+mem,-hex,-file --output=default,-inhx032 --runtime=default,+clear,+init,-keep,-no_startup,-download,+config,+clib,-plib --output=-mcof,+elf:multilocs --stack=compiled:auto:auto:auto "--errformat=%f:%l: error: (%n) %s" "--warnformat=%f:%l: warning: (%n) %s" "--msgformat=%f:%l: advisory: (%n) %s"      --memorysummary dist/default/production/memoryfile.xml -odist/default/production/TokenOverWiFi.X.production.elf  build/default/production/TokMain.p1 build/default/production/Wifi.p1 build/default/production/TimerSetup.p1     
Microchip MPLAB XC8 C Compiler (Free Mode) V1.44
Build date: Sep 13 2017
Part Support Version: 1.44
Copyright (C) 2017 Microchip Technology Inc.
License type: Node Configuration

:: warning: (1273) Omniscient Code Generation not available in Free mode
TimerSetup.c:4: error: (1098) conflicting declarations for variable "_Timer1Init" (TokMain.c:81)
make[2]: *** [dist/default/production/TokenOverWiFi.X.production.hex] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
(908) exit status = 1
nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:163: recipe for target 'dist/default/production/TokenOverWiFi.X.production.hex' failed
make[2]: Leaving directory 'E:/pk/TokenOverWiFi.X'
nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:90: recipe for target '.build-conf' failed
make[1]: Leaving directory 'E:/pk/TokenOverWiFi.X'
nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target '.build-impl' failed

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 805ms)
```

**Edit**

The code compiles successfully when I comment out my other header file. How??

Comment: Probably the function `Timer1Init` has already a prototype declaration elsewhere. You can either search the include directories for that string, or you run only the preprocessor and look in the output where and with what prototype the function is declared.

Comment: Not related to the problem, but to get C++ compatibility, the functions must be `void Timer1Init (void)`. Empty parameter list has different meanings in C and C++.

Comment: Does the error message the place of the prototype? Does `xc.h` provide a prototype?

Comment: Does the error message really mention "variable"? Please copy&paste the complete message

Comment: @harper I have changed the name of prototype and header file several times but nothing happened. Same error!!

Comment: @Lundin tried void Timer1Init (void) but still the same!!

Comment: @Gerhardh Added full error message to the topic!

Comment: @harper The code compiles successfully when I comment out my other header file. How??

Comment: The conflicting declaraion is caused by the implicit declaration in `TokMain.c:81` which is reported a few lines earlier in your log.

Comment: General rule: Start reading your warnings from the top. Warning or errors below might be caused by the warnings mentioned above.

Comment: @Gerhardh That warning only pop up when I do a Clean and build. The second time when I tried to build the warning was not there..

Comment: Probably you call the function incorrectly, or you include .c files somewhere etc. Seems the error is in "TokMain.c" and not in the posted code.

Comment: @Lundin edited my topic with my whole code!

Comment: @PraveenKumarPS Yep, the bug is obvious to me now, please see the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you use the same name for the header guards in every header file, so you block the compiler from seeing most of the code.

```
#ifndef XC_HEADER_TEMPLATE_H
#define XC_HEADER_TEMPLATE_H
```

This should be something like `#ifndef WIFI_H`, `#ifndef TIMER_SETUP_H` etc instead. Pick an unique name per header file.